# OS and/or IIS Caching

Tags: file-io, filesystems, webserver, performance

Is there a way where I can force caching files at an OS level and/or Web Server level (IIS)

The problem I am facing is that there a many static files ( xslt's for example ) that need to be loaded again and again - and I want to load all these files to memory so that no time wasted on hard disk I/O.

(1) I want to cache it at the OS level so that *every program* that runs on my OS and which tries to read a file must read it from memory. I want no changing in program source code - it must happen transparently. For example,  `read("c:\abc.txt")` must not cause a disk I/O, it must read it from the memory.

(2) Achieving similar thing in IIS. I've read few things about output caching for database queries - but how to achieve it for files?

All suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [some tricks used by SO itself](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/). One was that they moved all their static content off to another domain for efficiency.

The problem with default set ups for Apache (at a minimum) is that the web server will pass all requests through to an app server to see if the content is meant to be dynamic. That's a huge waste for content that you *know* to be static.

Far better to set up a separate domain for static content *without* an app server. That way, the static requests are not sent unnecessarily to another layer and the web server can run much faster.

Even in a setup where there's not another layer invoked every time, there are other reasons for a separate domain, as you'll see from that link (specifically removing cookies which both reduces traffic and improves the chances of the Internet caching your data).

Comment: The separate domain practice looks good, and I'll implement it if I can't get any other better response. Also, the method works only with *web requests* and not with local applications. Thanks